# Asignar diferentes acciones a un Floating Button en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, floating-action-button

Tengo un `FloatingActionButton` general y 3 `Fragments` que se cargan con un `ViewPager`

Siguiendo la [guía de diseño de Google](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#behavior), muestra que el `FloatingActionButton` esté en el `parent` y no en cada fragment

video:
https://material.io/design/assets/1CFlxacAgTNwbHddEylfR0iqC6LBtLbej/fab-layout-transition-do-v01.mp4

Tengo la siguientes dudas:

- Asignar funcionalidad dependiendo del fragment
- Cambiar el icono
- Se oculte y se muestre en cada cambio de página.

layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solucionado**

Partiendo de ese punto de solución en [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516130/is-it-possible-to-set-different-actions-for-floating-action-button-in-differet-f)

**MainActivity.java**

```
private FloatingActionButton fab;
...
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_action);
```

crear funciones publicas para mostrar y ocultar el botón

```
public void showFloatingActionButton() {
    fab.show();
}

public void hideFloatingActionButton() {
    fab.hide();
}
```

**Fragmentos**

En cada fragmento que se quiere usar el `FloatingActionButton` y asignar una funcinalidad en concreta

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
        onResume();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!getUserVisibleHint()) {
        return;
    }

    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    if (mainActivity != null) {

        mainActivity.showFloatingActionButton(); //fuerza la visibilidad

        FloatingActionButton fab = mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.fab_action);

        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_send_black_24dp); //Cambiar icono

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "pub action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Si el fragment queremos que no se visualice el `FloatingActionButton`
usar `mainActivity.hideFloatingActionButton()`

Para cambiar la funcionalidad se modifica:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Nueva funcionalidad
    }
});
```

**Ocultar el FloatingActionButton**

En cada transición de página se debe ocultar.

en `MainActivity.java`

```
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout) {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            hideFloatingActionButton();
        }
    });
```